# Lotus notes document saved with mendatory field missing

Tags: save, document, lotus-notes

Here is the definition of my problem. I have a Notes application which opens a Form using the formula @DialogBox. In that form, I have a field which is mandatory by its input validation usign this formula:

```
@If(NotificationTitle = ""; @Failure("The Title field is mandatory...") ; @Success)
```

Pretty simple uh?! Now the problem is, SOMEHOW, SOMEONE did SOMETHING and got that document saved with empty value. Anybody has an idea on how he could have done that? I know that wonderful phrase that says "90% of the clients are idiots", but how can you save a document with mendatory fields empty? The problem is that this empty field made the whole web-based application down. We don't want it to happen again, so we'll probably put a condition on the column of the view to show something when it's empty, but I wondered how it could have been empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You say it is a web-based application. The input validation only works on the client side.  Perhaps the bad value was added on the web side?

Also, there are many ways to add values to a Notes Document without being subject to input validation which only fires when the form is open.  Notes Agents can alter item values.  Also smart icon formulas can be setup to change field values.  Any chance you can see who made the change?  That would help narrow it down.

Comment: It was a human being that modified the document. And when I say it's web-based, it's just a part of the application. The form with the mendatory field is notes-based!

Comment: It will not work in WEB trying with any form or any thing . It notes formulas do not work in web full stop

Comment: @Java, who are you directing that comment to?  Also, I'm not clear on your point?  Could you rephrase your comment?

Comment: Was directed to OP in your support sorry I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Java, no problem.  I thought that might be the case but just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

On face-value of the info you have provided, this sounds like the data is exclusively entered through the Notes client ? If so, try retesting your application, and put a blank space in the mandatory field. I suspect that it will pass, and save the details because it's not really blank, a space character is still a character. To validate "real" blank fields, try this

> @If(@trim(NotificationTitle) = ""; 
>       @Failure("The Title field is mandatory...") ; 
>       @Success)

Note the [@trim](http://www.codestore.net/help/help85_designer.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/35e2f772c2f550f3852574cf006b567d?OpenDocument) formula in the condition test, this will cleanse the field of redundant trailing and leading spaces whilst doing validation. You need to be explicit about empty fields.

If however, the user enters data via the web, you will need to add javascript to validate this on the client side, and, you can use a "webquerysave" agent, to test on the server prior to saving the data. There is quite a bit of info on the web about using webquerysave agents, some good sources can be found [here](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Best-practices-for-using-the-Lotus-Notes-WebQuerySave-agent) and [here](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/srch?SearchView&Query=webquerysave&SearchFuzzy=TRUE&start=1&Count=10&SearchType=srch).

Finally, check the [AutoReload property](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/1c17bf57dc1007ec8525642e007537a3?OpenDocument) and [reload method](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/5763b32a3999f4668525642e0076d227?OpenDocument) of the [NotesUIdocument](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/a1d792857da52f638525630f004e7ab8/6eb903cbb53efbd88525642e007687e3?OpenDocument) as there is some [un-intuitive behaviour](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Pitfall_on_NotesUiDocument_vs._NotesDocument_field_changes-unexpected_Reload_) for it as well.

Comment: First, thank you for answering! You idea of the space instead of blank was well thought, though I already tryied this. The problem is really that there was a document properly saved with that mendatory field blank. There was absolutly no value in it! I know there is a problem with the way notes process the documents for saving, espescially when you have one instance of the NotesDocument in memory that you got with NoteUIDocument. When you modify the NotesDocument and save it, the original document that is in the NotesUIDocument is save instead... I couldn't repare that glitch either...

Comment: You will need to add lots of debugging now with messagebox or print statements, and call reload (or set autoreload), and see when values are set onto the back end document. Good place to check values is putting debug in these events queryrecalc, postrecalc, querysave and postsave. I have updated my answer with links relating to NotesUIDocument, AutoReload property, and Reload method. Hope this addresses your bugs.

Comment: Sorry, but it happened once in a while! And we cannot debug the production environment, it doesn't make sense. There are migration procedures and steps to do before trying things in production. Thanks for answering though, any answer might be good!

Comment: Sporadic errors are hard to trace. The only option you have now, (I think), is to setup an applog (see my updated answer), then lace your code with debug statements that will write to the log to report the current value of the field in question at the events I specified in my answer, if it changes to a blank value you can at least determine at which point it occurs. That would reduce where you have to search in the code.